# Assembly binding error - fusion log and dependency browser mismatch

Tags: .net, fusion

I'm chasing down an assembly loading/binding error that has popped up recently.  During my investigation I've found a confusing contradiction (assuming I'm parsing the fusion log correctly).

The exception that is thrown by my application at startup states:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

Some recent project changes that I made should not require the strongly named assembly  "Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI".  After confirming that all my solution projects are indeed referencing the unsigned assemblies I then fired up a [dependency browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Assemblydependencies.aspx) to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  Everything checked out and I confirmed I didn't have any "old" references to the old assemblies.  Of course I cleaned and rebuilt my project as well.

I then researched further and fired up the fusion log viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) and configured it to display binding errors.  I viewed the log and found the binding error.  The detail log is where the confusion starts; it lists the "Calling assembly" as an assembly that has NO bindings (that I can determine) to the missing assembly.  Ah, it's hard to explain.  Here is the log:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/15/2010 @ 7:00:18 PM) ***
>
> The operation failed.
>
> Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
>   Running under executable  C:\Program Files\PMT\Office App\1.1.1.7\OfficeApp.exe
>
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: User = PMD\sklett
>
> LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>    (Fully-specified)
>
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/PMT/Office App/1.1.1.7/
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
>
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL
>
> LOG: AppName = OfficeApp.exe
>
> Calling assembly : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
>
> ===
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\PMT\Office App\1.1.1.7\OfficeApp.exe.config
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>
> LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PMT/Office App/1.1.1.7/Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.DLL.
>
> LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\PMT\Office App\1.1.1.7\Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.dll
>
> LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
>
> LOG: Assembly Name is: Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI, Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
>
> ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
>
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Now the calling assembly "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" does not have any listed (via dependency browser) dependencies to "Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI".  Not only that, but it shouldn't have any.

the fusion log has stopped me in my tracks, fusion log has led to CONfusion! ;0)

Hopefully I supplied enough info for some wise expert to clue me in on what I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you expect not to have a strong name reference to Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI? Did you recompile it yourself without a SNK and change all of your project references?

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you have a strong named copy of Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI in your GAC?

Comment: @JeffN825 - "Did you recompile it yourself without a SNK and change all of your project references?" Yes, this is exactly what I did.  I also checked the GAC (gacutil -l) and there are NO P&P assemblies listed.

Comment: And the GAC on your build box doesn't contain the CompositeUI dlls either? I know this isn't what you want to hear, but the fact that it KNOWs the PublicKeyToken (31bf3856ad364e35) in the error says to me that one of your references is still pointing to a strong signed copy of the dll...

Comment: @JeffN825 - Not in the GAC on either of my dev machines.  I should explain that I store binaries that my projects will reference in a specific location.  This allows me to replace those assemblies with a new or modified version without needing to update all my projects.  So if project A, B and C all have a ref to C:\Tools\Lib\MyStuff.dll I can then just update that single location and all projects work fine. Except the P&P stuff where they store a lot of EntLib full binding info in the config files.  I have checked for CAB bindings in config files and there are NONE.  This is why I'm stumped..

Comment: @JeffN825 - Even if it were in the GAC it doesn't explain my confusion over the fusion log showing that EntLib.Common is trying to load CAB stuff.  Not only does the dependency browser not show that reference it's also completely illogical that EntLib would have CAB dependencies.  Other way around maybe, but EntLib wouldn't link to CAB.

Comment: Just because EntLib Common is trying to load the assembly doesn't mean that it's referencing it. Consider the scenario where reflection is used to resolve a type by name. A full stack trace might be helpful here.

Comment: Do you have notepad++ installed or the like? I would suggest doing a search on the content of all files in your solution directory (including the csproj files, which is why you need to use an external program) for the string "31bf3856ad364e35".

Comment: By the way, you're not using other CAB dlls that have not been rebuilt without the SNK, are you? And are you sure that when you rebuilt the CAB dlls (like the WinForms one) you refreshed the reference to the non SN'd CompositeUI dll?

Comment: @JeffN825 - You're right that a runtime-created dependency can exist.  I'm making a bold assumption that EntLib isn't loading up CAB because CAB is basically dead and the version of EntLib was released well after CABs funeral.  Additionally there is no logical dependency between the two blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if an answer is appropriate or an additional comment, please excuse me if I have chosen incorrectly.  ;0)

The good news is that after a reboot (power loss actually) the problem went away.  I don't know how or why this solved it, I was very meticulous in my researching the problem but sure enough a reboot made it go away!

Thanks to JeffN825 for sticking with it and offering assistance, I voted up some of your comments.

Comment: Sometimes I've seen very pesky obj directories (and their contents) stick around even after a clean and rebuild, until I actually restart VS, then clean and rebuild...Glad it's fixed!